# AngularJS: why empty model fields are removed from object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I have a model attached to a form which is something like that:

```
$scope.location = { description: "my descriptive description", address: "blah" }
```

Cleaning the field "description" in the form, which is bound to ng-model="location.description", removes the field from $scope.location which becomes:

```
$scope.location = { address: "blah" }
```

Now I would like it to retain the "description" field. What can I do in order to achieve
this behaviour?

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you provide a jsFiddle with your code (and a bit more details, like browser used). The thing is that I can't reproduce it on Chrome with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/myMyQ/1/, but probably your use case is different.

Comment: Finally I've understood why the field disappears. Doesn't depend on the browser. The input field has a "required" added to it which looks like the source of this behaviour. Removing required makes everything work as expected. Now it's just a matter to trying to make "required" behave the same way. Thanks for your support!

Comment: yes, I was suspecting that this is due to validation. The thing with AngularJS validators is that the model won't be bound till it passes validation, hence the observed behavior. Glad that you've got it figured out now.

Comment: There is a difference between 'required' and 'ng-required'. For me 'required' was deleting the property, 'ng-required' wasn't.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource is there any tricks to reproduce this behaviour on any input, should one desire it?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using the ng-change directive:

```
<input ng-model="desc" ng-change="setDescription()">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.setDescription = function(){
    $scope.location.description = $scope.desc ? $scope.desc: "default" 
}
```

Building off of Kozlowski's comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myMyQ/2/

Comment: Thanks Merbs for your support too.